# JS & EXT JS: function inside a function scope misunderstanding

Tags: javascript, extjs, scope

im having some trouble with the following code:

```
Ext.define('...controller...', {
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

init: function() {
    ...
},

crearLoginWindow:function(){

    var loginWindow = Ext.create('Proto1.view.adminbd.LoginWindowBDView', {
        itemId: 'loginwindow',
        autoShow: true,
        modal: true
    });

    Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#loginwindow > button[text="Cancelar"]')[0].on('click', function(){loginWindow.close()});

    //Cant call 'enviarLogin' function if its inside 'crearLoginWindow'
    Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#loginwindow > button[text="Conectar"]')[0].on('click', this.enviarLogin, this);

    var enviarLogin = function(){
        console.log('login')
    }

}

});
```

I want to be able to call 'enviarLogin' inside 'crearLoginWindow' function but it throws a reference error. If the function is placed outside 'crearLoginWindow' it will work.

Being these two lines the source of trouble:

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#loginwindow > button[text="Conectar"]')[0].on('click', this.enviarLogin, this);

var enviarLogin = function(){
    console.log('login')
}
```

I've tried different scope variants such as;

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#loginwindow > button[text="Conectar"]')[0].on('click', this.crearLoginWindow.enviarLogin);
this.enviarLogin = function(){
    console.log('login')
}
```

Which makes sense with what i think i understand about scope and the need to specify the place where the function resides to execute it.

Id appreciate a solution because this problem makes my code very messy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply defining a function within another function doesn't attach it to any object or instance, so `this.enviarLogin` won't work. There are two basic options here:

1. Just define the inner function as you're doing (moving it up above your handler assignment), and reference it directly by name:

   ```
   var enviarLogin = function(){
       console.log('login')
   };

   Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#loginwindow > button[text="Conectar"]')[0]
       .on('click', enviarLogin);
   ```
2. Define `enviarLogin` as a method, the same way you are defining `crearLoginWindow`:

   ```
   Ext.define('...controller...', {
       extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

       init: function() { ... },

       crearLoginWindow: function(){
           // ...

           Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#loginwindow > button[text="Conectar"]')[0]
               .on('click', this.enviarLogin, this);
       },

       enviarLogin: function(){
           console.log('login')
       }

   });
   ```

The first version may be better if you don't need to reference `enviarLogin` outside of the `crearLoginWindow` method. The second is better if you do need to reference `enviarLogin` elsewhere, and it makes using `this` in `enviarLogin` clearer.

Comment: Thanks, if theres no simple way to put the function below, option 1 seems the best solution to keep my code clearer for this matter.

Comment: You can use option one with the function definition below if you use a function declaration rather than a function expression: `function enviarLogin() {...}` - see [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/javascript-var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)

Comment: Great, now i can put all the 'helpers' where i want and also i've noticed that the 'sub function' keeps being private to the 'function container'.